# is it sufficient to remove a file from the git repo history by dropping the commit?

Tags: git

We have a git repo where someone accidentally committed a file `test.csv` which contains some test data - the file isn't actually required in the repo. The commit has been pushed to github though no-one else is using the branch so force pushing is something that I can do.

We could do a `git rm` on the file but I believe this will mean the file will still exist in the git repo forever and given its a sizeable file, that worries me.

I basically want to remove the file for the history. Is it sufficient to drop the commit (probably using a git interactive rebase) in order for any trace of the file to disappear from the repo?

Using interactive rebase isn't an issue here (assuming it does what I need) because the commit in question has not yet made its way out of the feature branch to where it was originally committed.

---

UPDATE A commenter has told me that an interactive rebase is not sufficient here (thank you to that person) hence my question becomes.... how do I remove all traces of this file from the git repo?

Comment: It will _appear_ to work, in that the visible history won't show the file, but of course the commits containing the file will still be present on the server.

Comment: Even if I drop the commit using interactive rebase?

Comment: If what you say is true then my question becomes... how do I remove any trace of the file from the git repo?

Comment: Commits are not immediately destroyed just because they are dropped. The point is that if this is a security issue, merely dropping the commit won't necessarily solve it.

Comment: Got it, thank you.

Comment: [Git - Rewriting Hisotry](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) - it depends on where the commit is. Recent is easier, but you may need force push or other admin type permissions on your host. Also based on the host, you may or may not have access to do things like the nuclear option of filter-branch.

Comment: force push (`git push -f`) is not a problem, I have permission to do that and no-one else is using the pushed branch. Are you saying that an interactive rebase followed by a force push will achieve what I need? | I don't know what filter-branch is so I will go and educate myself about that.

Comment: Did you consider reading the docs? https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository

Comment: Might be silly but how about removing the branch?

Comment: Didn't know about `filter-branch` so it looks overly comnplicated to me maybe because of that. `git rebase -i HEAD~<n>` where `<n>` must be high enough to include the mentioned commit, followed by `git push -f` should do the trick.

Comment: "Might be silly but how about removing the branch?" I assume would work, just was hoping for something a bit more elegant, partly because there are quite a lot of other commits in the branch.

Comment: "Did you consider reading the docs?" Would need to know about such a doc in the first place. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @MarcelloRomani thank you, that was the answer I was hoping for.

Comment: @jamiet I'm interested in why interactive rebase is not sufficient...

Comment: @MarcelloRomani Those weren’t my words. I was paraphrasing (perhaps wrongly) the comments above from Matt.

Comment: Sure, I know :) I just saw you updated your question to include that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We could do a `git rm` on the file but I believe this will mean the file will still exist in the git repo forever and given its a sizeable file, that worries me.

That's correct: no *existing* commit can ever be changed.

> I basically want to remove the file for the history. Is it sufficient to drop the commit (probably using a git interactive rebase) in order for any trace of the file to disappear from the repo?

That *can* suffice.

The trick to understanding all of this is to know the following:

- No commit can ever change.  Once made, *that* commit, as identified by its hash ID, has *that* content, forever, or at least as long as that commit continues to exist.
- Every commit contains the hash ID(s) of some previous (or *parent*) commit(s).  Most commits contain exactly one parent hash ID.  (That's in addition to the rest of the stuff the commit contains: a full snapshot of every file, for instance.)
- The way Git *finds* commits—besides directly, by hash ID—is, normally, to start with some *name*.  For instance, we might give Git the branch name `feature`.  This branch name contains the hash ID of *one* commit.  By definition, that one commit *is* the *last* commit in that branch.

Git commits contain the hash ID(s) of their immediate parent(s).  This means that they "point backwards".  That is, if we were to draw a simple chain of commits, using uppercase letters to stand in for the big ugly random-looking hash IDs, we'd get this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H` stands in for the hash ID of the *last* commit in this chain.  The commit itself contains the raw hash ID of earlier commit `G`, which in turn contains the hash ID of still-earlier commit `F`, and so on.

The hash IDs are the "true names" of the commit.  They are how Git finds the internal commit objects in the big database that Git keeps of "all the Git objects I have".  But somehow Git has to *get* the hash IDs, from somewhere.  Where will Git get the hash ID of commit `H`?  The answer is: from some *branch name:*

```
...--F--G--H   <-- feature
```

Here, we've gotten lazy about drawing the backwards arrows within commits.  They're *necessarily* backwards, because when we made `G`, we had no idea what hash ID `H` would have, so `G` couldn't point forward to `H`, and once we did make `G`, we can't *change* it either.  But we do know `G`'s ID when we make `H`, because `G`'s ID never changes, because `G` never changes, and the hash IDs are just cryptographic checksums of the contents of the commit.  So `H` can point to `G`, but not vice versa.

The act of adding a *new* commit to a branch consists of:

- saving a snapshot of all files (every commit holds a full snapshot of all files);
- obtaining and saving the appropriate metadata, such as the name and email address of whoever's making the commit right now, and the hash ID of the *current commit* to use as the parent;
- writing all this out and obtaining its unique cryptographic checksum; and
- last, writing the *new hash ID* into the *current branch name*.

This makes a new commit `I` that points back to `H`:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I
```

and the last step—writing the ID into the *current branch name*—makes the *name* point to commit `I` instead of commit `H`, so that we don't need to put `I` on a separate line after all:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- feature
```

That's how we *add* commits.  But what if one of them is "bad" somehow?

Well, if commit `I` is bad, we can just "shove it out of the way" right now:

```
             I
            /
...--F--G--H--J   <-- feature
```

We do this by making our new commit `J` now, but making its *parent* be commit `H` instead of commit `I`.  Then we write `J`'s hash ID into the name `feature`.  *Commit `I` still exists, but without a branch name, Git never looks for it.*

The command that does this—write a new commit but use the *current commit's parent* as the parent of the *new* commit, "shoving the commit aside" like this, is `git commit --amend`.  This doesn't actually *change* a commit, despite the `--amend` name.  But we use it all the time, to replace a slightly broken final commit that we know nobody else has yet.  That's pretty safe: nobody else *has* commit `I`, so if we replace with commit `J`, who will ever even know (other than ourselves)?

#### This is where rebase or filter-branch or The BFG comes in

Replacing the last commit at the *end* of a branch is pretty easy, but what if our mistake starts not at commit `I`, but rather at commit `G`?  Suppose commit `G` has the big `test.csv` file in it:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- feature
```

Because every commit has every file, commits `H` and `I` also have the big file.  We'll need to make a new and improved version of `G`.  We'll do this by *extracting* the entire `G` commit, *removing* the one big file, and committing, *while* we have commit `F` out as the *current commit*.  Let's call this new commit `G'`, to indicate that we made it *from* `G`, and draw it in:

```
       G--H--I   <-- feature
      /
...--F   <-- ???
      \
       G'  <-- ???
```

Now we'll make a new and improved `H` and call it `H'`:

```
       G--H--I   <-- feature
      /
...--F
      \
       G'-H'  <-- ???
```

To make `H'`, we can:

- check out all the files from `H` and remove the big one; or
- figure out what changed from `G` to `H`, and apply the same changes to `G'`.

Either method works fine.  Then we have to copy `I` to a new and improved `I'`:

```
       G--H--I   <-- feature
      /
...--F
      \
       G'-H'-I'  <-- ???
```

We can, again, use the same technique: copy all the files from `I` and remove the unwanted one, or figure out the difference from `H` to `I` and apply that to `H'`.

Last, now that we've made these new and improved *copies*, we yank the name `feature` off commit `I` and make it point to `I'` instead:

```
       G--H--I   [abandoned]
      /
...--F
      \
       G'-H'-I'  <-- feature
```

As before, abandoning the old commits does not actually remove them yet.  Git will *eventually* (via `git gc`) notice that nobody uses or cares about them, and clean them out, provided no *other branch names* reach these commits.

#### Should you use rebase, or filter-branch, or The BFG, or what?

"Yes."  You should probably use one of these tools.  You *can* do the whole thing by hand, but the tools make it easier.  The thing to know is *how* these tools do their jobs.

- Rebase is the least invasive in some sense, but also the weakest in some sense.  Rebase works by listing out some set of commits to copy, then copying them one at a time as if by `git cherry-pick`.  Used as an *interactive* rebase, it gives you the option to stop after each cherry-pick, or drop particular commits entirely, or do other special things.

  In this case, if the commit that adds the big file *only* adds the big file, rebase is a good tool because it's easy to just drop that commit entirely.  Although each commit *holds* a full snapshot of every file, the cherry-pick operation that rebase uses works by figuring out *what changed*, and applying those same changes.  So if you completely drop a commit whose change was "add big file", you don't add the file.  Your next commit fixes some other file, so you copy that one by fixing the other file, and the commit after that adds some new file, so you keep that by adding the new file, and so on.
- `git filter-branch` comes with Git.  It's very powerful, and extremely awkward to use.  It's officially deprecated now ("don't use this any more if you can avoid it").

  Filter-branch works by extracting each commit, one at a time, then making arbitrary changes, then writing out the new result.  This gives you total control, at the cost of making you take total control.
- `git filter-repo` is the new replacement for `git filter-branch`.  It's much more pleasant to use, and smarter, although it does not yet do everything and—perhaps more importantly—doesn't come with Git.

  Filter-repo works by *not* changing the *original* repository.  Instead, it makes an all-new repository, by taking each commit from the original, making changes in a more pleasant environment (easier to manage), and making a new commit in the all-new repository.  Because Git commits have cryptographic checksums, if the new commit is 100% bit-for-bit identical to the original commit, its hash ID matches, and the new repo is then compatible with the old one.
- The BFG has a more limited repertoire than `git filter-branch`, which makes it easier to use (by a lot).  It's also faster (usually much faster).  It doesn't come with Git though.  Fundamentally it works a lot like filter-branch internally.

For this particular case, I'd probably just use `git rebase` myself.

#### Rebase caveat

In my illustration of rebase, I drew this:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- feature
```

becoming:

```
       G--H--I   [abandoned]
      /
...--F--G'-H'-I'  <-- feature
```

From your description, this is exactly what you'll get, and it will be fine.  But suppose we start with a slightly more complicated picture:

```
             J   <-- feature2
            /
...--F--G--H--I   <-- feature
```

When we "replace" `G` with the new and improved `G'`, and so on, we end up with this:

```
            I   [abandoned]
           /
       G--H--J   <-- feature2
      /
...--F--G'-H'-I'  <-- feature
```

That is, commit `J` remains reachable: it's found through the name `feature2`.  The commit that is the parent of `J` is—still!—`H`.  That commit still has `G` as its parent, which still has `F` as its parent.  The `F-G-H` sequence was, earlier, on *both branches*.  Now it's still on the `feature2` branch, even though the `G-H` commits are "bad" because they contain the large file.

The fancier commands—filter-branch, filter-repo, and the BFG—*can* handle this all at once, as they are willing to look over (and copy!) the entire repository if needed.  Rebase can't, because it doesn't.  You *can* use multiple separate rebase operations here, but it gets messy.

Answer (score 3):

Use [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to clean data out of repository history.